# Limit labesl on chart.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, charts, chart.js

I am limiting `x-axis` labels to 5, I used `showXLabels: 5` but it's not working. I am using `Chart.bundle.js` `version 2.7.2`

Code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="col_chart"></canvas>
<script>
var savingCanvas = document.getElementById("col_chart");
var savingData = {
  label: 'Data',
  backgroundColor: "rgba(51,204,255,1)",
  data: [5427, 5243, 5514, 3933, 1326, 687, 1271, 1638]
};

var barChart = new Chart(savingCanvas, {
  type: 'bar',
  showXLabels: 5,
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],
    datasets: [savingData]
  }
});
</script>
</body>
```

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0):

`showXLabels` is [not documented](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/?q=showXLabels). Where did you find this option?

You create your chart with a [Category](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html) X-axis. As such, Chart.js simply renders the labels and data provided. The only way to limit to 5 would be to reduce your `labels` array to 5 elements.

A [Linear](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) axis has a `maxTicksLimit` property, but that's not applicable here.